# Underlining user input in python3

Tags: python

I was wondering how I can set up my program whereby the user input is underlined without having to import a different system. I have an idea to use my own class as follows:

```
class Colors:

    underline = '\033[04m'
```

but I am stuck because I don't know how to reflect that on user input

the part underlined is what the user has to input

[image]

Comment: Question is not clear. Can you give more details?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
input('User input: \033[4m\0')
```

## EDIT - end the underlining

This works on mine. The 'end' parameter is just so the print does not change the line.

```
input('User input: \033[4m\0')
print('\033[0m', end='')
input('User input: \033[4m\0')
print('\033[0m', end='')
input('User input: \033[4m\0')
```

Comment: You forgot to turn down the underline. Even program is exited. The underline still work on! OSX 10.14 Python3.7

Comment: @Sarit ah I see, you are right. I tested this now and it works. Check the edit I did above (unable to format here).

Comment: Hm, this doesn't return any output when I run it. Am i missing something?

Comment: if you save it in a file and run it through the terminal you should be able to type the user input 3 times and see what you type underlined and the text 'User input: ' not underlined

Comment: Pretty cool. I am seeing the entire first line being underlined, but neat approach

Answer (score 2):

Using your colors class scheme:

```
class Colors:

    start_underline='\033[04m'
    end_underline = '\033[0m'


a = input('Enter the project name: ')
print (Colors.start_underline + '{}'.format(a) + Colors.end_underline)
```

Comment: colors should be Colors.

Comment: how should I underline text while I input in python console and at the same time end the underline... e.g enter some input: Mikey(this is underlined) then You have input: Mikey (no underline)